# Error in case construct with string comparison (scheme)

Tags: scheme

```
(define aaa ;;val:string  
(lambda(x)  ;;x:string
 (case
    ((string=? (substring x 0 1) "+") (aaa(substring x 1)))
    ((string=? "a" "b")(string-append("-" (aaa(substring x 1)))))
    ((char=?(string-ref x 0)#\.) (-404))
    (else
     (if (= (findpoint x) -1)
       "a"
       "b"
    )     
   )
  )  
) 
)
```

Hello, I have a problem with DrRacket:
When I try to run this code, it gives me the error:

> case: expected a symbol (without its quote) or a number as a choice, but found a string

referring to the line (5):

> ((string=? "a" "b")(string-append("-" (aaa(substring x 1)))))

This line was actually supposed to look like this,

> ((string=? **(substring x 0 1) "+"**)(string-append("-" (aaa(substring x 1)))))

but I thought that using two strings "a" "b" would ease to spot the problem. 
I don't understand why i get this error, since both "a" "b" are strings and not symbols or lists, and also I can't understand why I don't get this error on the previous line

CONTEXT:
the procedure is supposed check if the first character of a string is a +/-/., and then do thing through recursion using else (again, "a" "b" are examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are mixing `cond`, the flat if-elseif-else, and `case`, which is similar to a switch statement.

How to use `cond`:

```
(cond ((equal? 1 2) 'consequent)
      ((odd? 1) 'consequent2) ; as many terms as you want. It stops at the first true
      (else 'alternative))    ; or else it evaluates the alterntaive
; ==> consequent2
```

Vs how to use `case`

```
(case 'value4
  ((value1 value2) 'consequent)
  ((value3 value4) 'consequent2)
  (else 'default))
; ==> consequent2
```

Now that case statement is just sugar. Your Scheme implementation will make it into something similar to this:

```
(cond ((and (eqv? 'value4 'value1) (eqv? 'value4 'value2)) 'consequent)
      ((and (eqv? 'value4 'value3) (eqv? 'value4 'value4)) 'consequent2)
      (else 'default))
```

Thus notice the values to match in a case are treated as if they are quoted. Eg. you values can not be variables since they will only match their symbol.

If you want to use `case` I would have done this:

```
(define (first-letter-operator? str)
  (case (string-ref str 0)
    ((#\+ #\- #\.) #t)
    (else #f)))

(first-letter-operator? "+345634") ; ==> #t
(first-letter-operator? "hello")   ; ==> #f
```

Comment: Wow, I mixed up the two things, and i didn't notice... Sorry for the waste of time and thanks for the help!